# Padding between elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get rid of the gap in the middle of my page. I have tried multiple things such as setting my `.offer` css to

```
.offer {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    padding:0 4px 4px;
}
```

But nothing happens.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNLyZp

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `margin-bottom: 30px` from the .jumbotron css.

Or do this:

```
.jumbotron {
   padding-bottom: 0;
   margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you set the .jumbotron margin-bottom to 0
Attention to responsive media queries :)

Answer (score 0):

remove the `margin-bottom` from `jumbotron` class. avoid using `!important` as you might need to override your style